# MSMQ reading 1mb or larger message

Tags: msmq

I have an MSMQ message of about 2mb send from server A to server B. Server B does receive it, but when the Windows Service reads it (timeout is 5000 seconds), to insert it into the database, it doesn't. The message disappears off the queue though.

I suspect this might be happening with other (smaller) messages as well.

Any ideas on where to debug/setting etc?

Edit:

```
Dim m As Message
                Using msgQ As New MessageQueue(queueToRead, QueueAccessMode.Receive)
                    msgQ.Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter(New Type() {GetType(System.String)})

                    Dim msgs As MessageEnumerator = msgQ.GetMessageEnumerator2
                    While msgs.MoveNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(queueTimeout))
                        m = msgQ.ReceiveById(msgs.Current.Id, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                        UDTT = m.Label
                        recordSet = m.Body

                        'Log Transaction to DB here
                    End While
                End Using
```

Comment: MSMQ messages can be up to 4MB in size. Can you show the code where you read the message off the queue?

Comment: The queue in this case can handle up to 10mb (I checked). I added the code that reads the queue and inserts into a working table in MS SQL. It sends the message to the recipient and I can see it comes in on recipient level, but as soon as it's read off the queue, there's nothing logged in the database